# Usage of "from now on"

Tags: grammar

Can I use **"from now on"** with **present perfect tense**? I have a given an example. Please tell me if it is grammatical and if not, please give me an example sentence where I can use "from now on" with present perfect tense.

Here's the example:

- Peter, we have found you guilty of beating Sam So you **have been** suspended from the school from now on.

Answer (score 2):

"From now on" requires present or future tense, as it refers to something that starts now and continues.
If grandpa Peter tells that story to his grandchildren, he could say "From that day on, I have been suspended from school".

Answer (score 0):

From now on is usually used to emphasize a situation or event that will be different than the past:

From now on, we will take the bus to school instead of walk.

From now on, students will be suspended for 5 days instead of 3 for assaulting classmates.

Also consider:

Peter used to beat Sam until he was suspended.  From then on, he has been nice to Sam.

As for the example of "from now on" used with present perfect:

We've been told that, from now on, Peter has to check in with the school counselor every morning before going to class.